# How to prevent span float left fall in li

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How to prevent the button fall from the li. Im using bootstrap 3.0 and class pull-left for the button. when the space of word is to small. the button will fall out of the li.

Comment: What do you have and what have you tried?

Comment: if i remove float, it will be okey but it not go to right.  i want the button in the right and not fall.